# ¿Cómo cambiar el logo al activar el modo oscuro?

Tags: javascript, css

Como puedo cambiar de logo en el mismo instante que active o desactive el modo oscuro?. He intentado esto con Js pero la verdad estoy perdido. Agradecería una ayuda con esto.
hice estas funciones para actualizar las rutas del logo:
main.js:

```
 function dark () {
    document.getElementById('logo').src = "../img/logo_dark.svg";// aquí actualizo la ruta para traer el logo que usare en modo oscuro
   }
   function light () {
    document.getElementById('logo').src = "../img/logo.svg"; // aquí actualizo la ruta para traer el logo que usare en modo claro
   }
```

html:

```
<input class="btn-toggle" type="checkbox" onclick="dark(),light()">// aquí llamo a las funciones
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main.js:

```js
function changeLogo(element) {

    // Si el atributo es light
    if(element.getAttribute("theme") == "light"){
        // Cambiamos el atributo theme del botón por dark y cambiamos el logo
        element.setAttribute("theme", "dark");
        document.getElementById('logo').src = "../img/logo_dark.svg"; 
    }else{
        // En caso de ser dark lo cambiamos por light
        element.setAttribute("theme", "light");
        document.getElementById('logo').src = "../img/logo.svg";
    }        
}
```

html:

```html
<!-- agregamos un atributo el cual nos permitirá saber el color actual -->
<input class="btn-toggle" type="checkbox" onclick="changeLogo(this)" theme="dark">
```

Comment: Tu código funciona bien pero, es importante que esplique sus funciones en lo mínimo posible. Esto es para que otras personas que tienen el mismo problema o busquen algo similar pueda entender el funcionamiento y hacer uso de ello y tal vez tú ganes más reputación. Te invito a que leas [answer] y sepáis ayudar

Comment: Hola, si tienes razón. pero no entiendo porque en mi proyecto no me estaba sirviendo, en un documento en blanco funciona. Al final por tiempo me toco resolverlo agregándole clases al SVG y usando variables en CSS.  El script que hiciste me sirvió para cambiar los iconos, solamente  cree otra función para que los mostrara al cargar la pagina. Gracias!